# java 11 and spring boot error: this_class should be module-info

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-11, java-module

I have created a simple Spring boot application, and I'm trying to move it to a newer jdk version. My plan was to use jlink and distribute it as a complete package. But I'm getting this error:

> this_class should be module-info

When I try to compile it with maven. If I remove the module-info it works (and it generates the self contained jar as expected). Am I missing something else?

module-info.java:

```
module operations {
requires static lombok;

requires commons.beanutils;
requires opencsv;
requires commons.net;
requires spring.data.mongodb;
requires spring.data.commons;
requires java.validation;
requires org.mongodb.bson;
requires spring.web;
requires spring.context;
requires spring.core;
requires spring.boot;

requires spring.beans;
requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
requires spring.context.support;
requires java.mail;
requires thymeleaf;
requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
requires java.annotation;
requires org.apache.commons.collections4;
requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
requires java.ws.rs;
requires spring.security.core;
requires spring.messaging;
requires spring.websocket;
requires java.management;
requires spring.security.web;
requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core;
requires spring.security.config;
requires java.security.sasl;

exports com.testapp.operations;
```

}

project structure:

```
src/main/java/
          ...module-info.java
          .../com/testapp/operations/(all classes)
pom.xml
```

Comment: when do you get to see that error? upon which command execution ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get it when executing mvn clean package

Comment: Is there any possibility that someone thing has renamed a regular class to module-info.class?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in certain dependencies which prevents the module from compiling correctly. In my case the problem was with the `cglib` library on the classpath (maven dependency):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my case the solution was to update the library to latest version 3.3.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The best way to find the offending library is to comment out the dependencies one by one and run the build after each such action. Once the code compiles correctly the problematic libary is identified. Try updating it or, if there is no update avilable, exclude it.

If exclusion is not an option, the possible solutionis to extract the code using the library to the separate module. This new module could be compiled as automatic module (without module-info.java).